# Generate CSV file in JSF 2.0

Tags: java, apache, csv, apache-poi

i am using apache poi and JSF 2.0 in my application to generate report in excel format.

Code Snipped to generate Excel.

```
final FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        final ExternalContext externalContext = facesContext
                .getExternalContext();
        externalContext.setResponseContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
            externalContext.setResponseHeader("Content-Disposition",
            "attachment; filename=\"Excel Sample");
        workbook.write(externalContext.getResponseOutputStream());
        facesContext.responseComplete();
```

As You can see i am adding "application/vnd.ms-excel"-  MIME type for the server. I am just playing around and wondering if we can change the MIME type to CSV. I am no more generating Excel file for report.

There is another function where i am fetching the data from the database and writing it to cells using HSSF object. and I call this method (code snippet) after writing data to each cell.

What I am supposed to write instead

> externalContext.setResponseContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");

So that it generates file with csv extension.

Comment: What are you after - the mimetype for CSV, or instructions on how to generate the contents of a CSV file?

Comment: @Gagravarr , I am writing to an excel file programatically using Java. The excel output files may contain 100,000 rows. This could lead to memory out of exception issue. I have read somewhere that most all existing Java APIs try to build the whole document in RAM at once. So we have decided to write data directly into CSV. I am looking for mimetype instrcution though, but how to generate CSV would be of great help, may be a snippet/algo would help. I would like to refrain using any third party library.

Comment: If you're happy to generate a .xlsx file rather than a .xls one, you can use SXSSF from POI to generate the file in a streaming manner. .xls files can't be generated the same way though, as there are too many references back and forward in the format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal mimetype for a CSV file is `text/csv`

When generating your file, be sure to quote values correctly. It may be worth using an existing library to ensure that's done, especially if you have complicated values

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the Answer, It did it work. But I somehow facing strange problem. After genertaing csv file using StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
"sb.append("hello").....etc etc"
and then I am doing this.
 sb.write(externalContext.getResponseOutputStream()); which is creating problem, Can you help me as how to write into output stream in this case.?

Answer (score 1):

```
response.setContentType("text/comma-separated-values; charset=utf8");
```